# how to dynamically add images to UI from code behind asp.net with all the styles already declared in .aspx page

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have developed a aspx page statically where the code is like

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="contain" id="subdiv" runat="server">

  <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" runat="server" />

    <label for="cb1">

        <img src="Images/download_image.jfif" runat="server" id="imagesrc"/>
           <label>some text</label>  

            </label>

 </div>
       </div>
```

For now I gave only one image in UI and trying to increase the count manually like below

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            Image img = new Image();
            img.ImageUrl = "~/Images/download_image.jfif";         
            subdiv.Controls.Add(img);
        }
```

the code i am trying is not working.
it is like images acting like checkboxes with a label caption.But the number of images depends on the data coming from a sql table and the image for all are same.How can i call the image which  is inside of div element and display it based on the count times from code behind so that all the css and js script will be applied .Please help me

Comment: have a look at [repeaters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [how to use a prepeater](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5089e0/how-to-use-repeater-control-in-Asp-Net/)

Comment: better to use any of these controls like GridView, ListView or Repeater .. other waay around use 'subdiv.controls.add(img)' in side loop.

Comment: The image is same for all the data that is coming from the table and  should be displayed side  by side and also associated with an url which downloads  respective file associated with the data

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to read from database you should use OdbcCommand and the code as follows

```
 using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(yourquery, cn))
            {
                using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var divHtml = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new 
                        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                        div.ID = "div";
                        div.InnerHtml = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));
                        Image img = new Image();
                        img.ImageUrl = "~/Images/download_image.jfif";
                        img.AlternateText = "Dynamic Images";
                        div.Controls.Add(img);
                        divHtml.append(div);
                    }
                    subdiv.InnerHtml = divHtml.ToString();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I have defined js and css for div and check box elements in .aspx page.Will it be applied to the adding image and div elements for the above mentioned code.

Comment: this code contains a div control thus you can add anything to it, but if you want to take actions on checkboxes and other elements I advise to use javascript and send and receive data to server using ajax

Comment: if you found it useful, don't forget to mark it as an answer ;)